# Using the indefinite article after no and not

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, negation

I was wondering if someone could help explain why we don't use the indefinite article in this sentence

> There is no couch in the living room

but we do use it in this sentence

> There isn't a couch in the living room?

Now I know it has something to do with no vs. not but I can't figure out how to explain to people why there is a difference.

Also, when I think about it, it seems like we almost never use 'a' after no but we do after not... but again, I just came seem to come up with a rule to explain it?

Thanks kindly....

Answer (score 5):

'No' as a determiner means 'not a/not one/not any'. If we said 'no a couch', we would effectively be saying 'not a a couch'.

More formally, 'no' and 'a' are central determiners, and central determiners are mutually exclusive - they cannot co-occur, as Sylvia Chalker notes in *The Oxford Companion to the English Language* (1992).

Comment: Very informative. +1.